# Xamarin PushAsync, an unhandled exception has occured

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have  a page where I have a REST API call and when debugged it brings the results succesfully, however we are getting an unhandled exception has occured, if we put a try catch, no detail is shown,

xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FCR.App.Views.DetailsContactNaPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListView x:Name="lstView" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding NombreCompleto}" Detail="{Binding Descripcion}" />
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="¿Desea continuar registrando el contacto?" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium"  />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="dismissbutton" Text="Sí" Clicked="OnDismissButtonClicked"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="dismissbutton2" Text="No" Clicked="Clearnextview"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then the method.

```
private async void Blurevent(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {

            if (txtPnombre.Text != null && txtPapellido.Text != null)
            {
                var nombre = txtPnombre.Text.Trim();
                var apellido = txtPapellido.Text.Trim();
                var result = await App.NaturalezaManager.GetNombresApellidos(nombre,apellido);
                if (result.Count >= 1)
                {
                   var respuesta = await DisplayAlert("Registros", "Se han encontrado registros, ¿Desea verlos?", "Sí","No");
                    if (respuesta)
                    {
                        var detallepage = new DetailsContactNaPage(result);


                            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(detallepage);



                        //await DisplayAlert("Registrados", result[0].PrimerNombre + " "+ result[0].PrimerApellido+ "", "Sí", "No");
                    }
                }

            }


        }
```

Update 1:

Error

> Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method
>   'Android.Widget.TextView.SetTextAppearance' not found.
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.BaseCellView.BaseCellView(Context
>   context, Cell cell):0
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.TextCellRenderer.TextCellView.TextCellRenderer(Context
>   context, Cell cell):0
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.TextCellRenderer.GetCellCore(Cell item,
>   View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context
>   context):0
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.CellRenderer.GetCell(Cell item, View
>   convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context
>   context):0
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.CellFactory.GetCell(Cell item, View
>   convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context, View
>   view):0
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.GetView(int position,
>   View convertView, ViewGroup
>   parent):0
>   Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetView_ILandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_(IntPtr
>   jnienv, IntPtr native__this, int position, IntPtr native_convertView,
>   IntPtr native_parent):0 at (wrapper
>   dynamic-method) System.Object:10d75808-73c9-4d3e-9e67-1b2609993ff0
>   (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr)
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ListViewAdapter.n_getView(Native
>   Method)
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ListViewAdapter.getView()ListViewAdapter.java:100
>   android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView()HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView()AbsListView.java:2346
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView()ListView.java:1876
>   android.widget.ListView.fillDown()ListView.java:702
>   android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop()ListView.java:763
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren()ListView.java:1685
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout()AbsListView.java:2148
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout()SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ListViewRenderer.n_onLayout(Native
>   Method)
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ListViewRenderer.onLayout()ListViewRenderer.java:65
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout()FormsViewGroup.java:29
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.VisualElementRenderer_1.n_onLayout(Native
>   Method)
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.VisualElementRenderer_1.onLayout()VisualElementRenderer_1.java:49
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout()FormsViewGroup.java:29
>   md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.Platform_ModalContainer.n_onLayout(Native
>   Method)
>   md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.Platform_ModalContainer.onLayout()Platform_ModalContainer.java:53
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.n_onLayout(Native
>   Method)
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.onLayout()PlatformRenderer.java:63
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout()RelativeLayout.java:1079
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren()FrameLayout.java:336
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout()FrameLayout.java:273
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame()LinearLayout.java:1735
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical()LinearLayout.java:1579
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout()LinearLayout.java:1488
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren()FrameLayout.java:336
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout()FrameLayout.java:273
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout()PhoneWindow.java:2934
>   android.view.View.layout()View.java:16639
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:5437
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout()ViewRootImpl.java:2179
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()ViewRootImpl.java:1939
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal()ViewRootImpl.java:1115
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run()ViewRootImpl.java:6023
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run()Choreographer.java:858
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks()Choreographer.java:670
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame()Choreographer.java:606
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run()Choreographer.java:844
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback()Handler.java:739
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:95
>   android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:148
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5461
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:726
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:616

Comment: try using HockeyApp (or another crash reporting tool) to capture it, or roll your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197474/handling-global-exception-xamarin-droid-ios

Comment: Typically these type of errors occur because of XAML issues. Make sure you have XAML compilation turned on `[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]`.

Comment: didnt know about HockeyApp, Amazing tool, now I will paste the crash report.

Comment: @SteveDavis should I put that in the PCL or android and ios projects?

Comment: Check your build options to target android 6 or higher. Also set the Linking option to None if the target doesn't help. Clean and rebuild when changing those

Comment: that fixed the problem! thanks Sten