# Xamarin.iOS unhandled crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a weird situation. Application crashes after 5-7 minutes usage without any logs. Application crashes only on a real device.  I have integrated HockeyApp but there no crash report after that crashes and no logs in debug console.

Clean and rebuild doesn't work.

Looks like memory leak, but I can't manage it.

How can I catch those crashes?

Comment: look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33197475

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov no effect.

Comment: The menu of VS , `View -> Other Windows - > Device Log`. Rebuild your project ,check log in window of Device Log First.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Nothing.

Comment: Okey, Have a try this,menu of VS , `Help -> Xamarin- > Open Logs..`

Comment: Check that your project whether has network request always working.If have suspend them first and rebuild project to test whether have a crash.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT logs doesn't display anything and this crashes also appears on release and debug modes and without attached debugger

Answer (score -1):

Try this implement method write log to file and read

```
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser +=  HandleAndroidException;
```

For IOS

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => {
        //todo
    };
```

Comment: he specifically says this is on iOS, not Android